# <li> is not making space for the content to grow

Tags: html, css

I have tried creating a ul li list. When the content inside the li is more, scroll appears. But a problem I m facing is that the li tag is not covering the whole width. It's coming outside

```css
.container{
  background: blue;
  padding:20px;
  width:220px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

ul li{
  background: white;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>New york</li>
    <li>Sierra Leone</li>
    <li>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet hhoihoihoihoihihihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihfhgfdhgddhgd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not like a word at all *hhoihoihoihoihihihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihfhgfdhgddhgd*, Try using meaningful content. To break words you can use *word-break: break-all;* css property.

Comment: _“But a problem I m facing is that the li tag is not covering the whole width.”_ - it is called _overflow_ for a reason.

Comment: set `overflow: inherit;` in `ul li {}`

Comment: display:inline-block for li

Answer (score 3):

You can use `word-break: break-all`

```css
.container{
  background: blue;
  padding:20px;
  width:220px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

ul li{
  background: white;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  min-width:100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>New york</li>
    <li>Sierra Leone</li>
    <li>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet hhoihoihoihoihihihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihfhgfdhgddhgd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want the scroll, when the content  is more and it should cover the whole li width

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x:auto;` set ul li to scrolling enabled having large content in li.

```css
.container{
  background: blue;
  padding:20px;
  width:220px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li{
  background: white;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  min-width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>New york</li>
    <li>Sierra Leone</li>
    <li>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet hhoihoihoihoihihihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihoihfhgfdhgddhgd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```